# sed permission denied on temporary file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

With `sed` I try to replace the value *0.1.233*... On the command line there is no problem; however, when putting this command in a shell script, I get an error:

```
sed: couldn't open temporary file ../project/cas-dp-ap/sedwi3jVw: Permission denied
```

I don't understand where this temporary sedwi file comes from.

Do you have any idea why I have this temporary file and how I can pass it?

```
$(sed -i "s/$current_version/$version/" $PATHPROJET$CREATE_PACKAGE/Chart.yaml)

++ sed -i s/0.1.233/0.1.234/ ../project/cas-dp-ap/Chart.yaml
sed: couldn't open temporary file ../project/cas-dp-ap/sedwi3jVw:   Permission denied
+ printf 'The version has been updated to : 0.1.234 \n\n \n\n'
The version has been updated to : 0.1.234 
+ printf '***********************************'
```

Comment: `sed -i` will try to create a temp file. Can you check if you have write permissions on the folder that it tries to create this temp file?

Comment: *＋1* for showing your debug output.

Answer (score 8):

`sed -i` is "in-place editing". However "in-place" isn't really. What happens is more like:

- create a temporary file
- run sed on original file and put changes into temporary file
- delete original file
- rename temporary file as original

For example, if we look at the inode of an edited file we can see that it is changed after sed has run:

```
$ echo hello > a
$ ln a b
$ ls -lai a b
19005916 -rw-rw-r-- 2 jhnc jhnc 6 Jan 31 12:25 a
19005916 -rw-rw-r-- 2 jhnc jhnc 6 Jan 31 12:25 b
$ sed -i 's/hello/goodbye/' a
$ ls -lai a b
19005942 -rw-rw-r-- 1 jhnc jhnc 8 Jan 31 12:25 a
19005916 -rw-rw-r-- 1 jhnc jhnc 6 Jan 31 12:25 b
$
```

This means that your script has to be able to create files in the folder where it is doing the "in-place" edit.

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax is identical on the command line and in a script.  If you used `$(...)` at the prompt then you would have received the same error.

```
sed -i "s/$current_version/$version/" "$PATHPROJET$CREATE_PACKAGE/Chart.yaml"
```

(Notice also the quoting around the file name. Probably your private variables should use lower case.)

The syntax

```
$(command)
```

takes the output from `command` and tries to execute it as a command.  Usually you would use this construct -- called a [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) -- to interpolate the output of a command into a string, like

```
echo "Today is $(date)"
```

(though `date +"Today is %c"` is probably a better way to do that particular thing).