# sed multiple different patterns: delete line following a pattern and the next line

Tags: sed

I want to find in a file multiple patterns and delete that line and the next line.

I.e. I want to delete all lines with .mkv .mp4 .avi and the (corresponding) next line.

I read what is written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4398433/1957820), so I tried to make use of it and  tried to change the file in place (-i):

```
sed -ei '/.mkv/{N;d}; /.mp4/{N;d}; /.avi/{N;d}' ${myfile}
and also:
sed -ei '/.mkv/{N;d}; -e /.mp4/{N;d}; -e /.avi/{N;d}' ${myfile}
```

But that didn't work.

The only thing what did work, but is actually not what I mean (coz I want it in place), is:

```
sed -e '/.mkv/{N;d};/.mp4/{N;d};/.avi/{N;d}' ${myfile} > 1.1
[ -f 1.1 ] && rm -f ${myfile} && mv 1.1 ${myfile}
```

So question is: how to find the multiple patterns and delete that line and the next ones in place with sed.

Comment: "that didn't work" is the worst problem statement as it tells us nothing about the problem. Tell us in what way "that didn't work" - wrong output, no output, error messages, etc.

Comment: since your third version (without `-i`) "work"ed but is otherwise identical to your second version, it is probably not sed that is the problem. Note that  "in place" is not really in place - your second and  third versions are approximately equivalent except the former creates the temporary file in a way that cannot collide with any existing filename - cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54460675/10971581

Comment: sed hs been started with the 'i' parameter and the file should be changed/edited. 'But didn't work' means here: the original file has not been changed at all. At my screen no error (messages) etc. I only see the lines with .mkv, .mp4 etc. So the -i seems not to work.

However, the answer from Potong gave me what I wanted/asked.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -Ei '/\.(mkv|mp4|avi)\b/{N;d}' file
```

Turn on extended regexp `-E` and inline replacement `-i`.

If a line contains a period, followed by either `mkv`, `mp4` or `avi`, followed by a word end then append the next line and delete both.

Comment: It is working now with your suggestion. Excellent, thank you so much